# JSF Validator compare to Strings for Equality

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

How would you compare two string for equality in a JSF Validator?

```
if (!settingsBean.getNewPassword().equals(settingsBean.getConfirmPassword())) {
    save = false;
    FacesUtils.addErrorMessage(null, "Password and Confirm Password are not same", null);
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a normal `Validator` on the second component and pass the value of the first component as attribute of the second component.

Thus, so

```xml
<h:inputSecret id="password" binding="#{passwordComponent}"
    value="#{bean.password}"
    required="true"
    requiredMessage="Please enter password" 
    validatorMessage="Please enter at least 8 characters">
    <f:validateLength minimum="8" />
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message for="password" />

<h:inputSecret id="confirmPassword" 
    required="#{not empty passwordComponent.value}"
    requiredMessage="Please confirm password"
    validatorMessage="Passwords are not equal">
    <f:validator validatorId="validateEqual" />
    <f:attribute name="otherValue" value="#{passwordComponent.value}" />
</h:inputSecret>
<h:message for="confirmPassword" />
```

*([note that `binding` on first component is exactly as-is; you shouldn't bind it to a bean property!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506679/what-is-component-binding-in-jsf-when-it-is-preferred-to-be-used/))*

with

```java
@FacesValidator(value="validateEqual")
public class ValidateEqual implements Validator<Object> {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        Object otherValue = component.getAttributes().get("otherValue");

        if (value == null || otherValue == null) {
            return; // Let required="true" handle.
        }

        if (!value.equals(otherValue)) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Values are not equal."));
        }
    }

}
```

If you happen to use the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org), then you can use `<o:validateEqual>` for this. This exact case of "confirm password" is demonstrated on [`<o:validateEqual>` showcase](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateEqual).

#### See also:

- [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

Comment: Hi BalusC, is there any other way to do this without binding the inputSecret component?

Comment: You could hardcode the ID and pass it instead. E.g. `<f:attribute name="componentId" value="formid:passwordid" />` and then use `UIViewRoot#findComponent()` to get the component. However this is only clumsy. Why the aversion against binding? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Isn't there additional overhead (memory wise) when adding bindings for components? Its probably minimal, but just a question.

Comment: It's very minimal. It's just one more reference to an existing object in memory. Referencing a String is actually potentially more expensive since the value doesn't necessarily already exist in the string pool.

Comment: I was just reading about OmniFaces on your blog. It's indeed a lot easier this way : a single tag in the view, and the job is done! I'm only starting to work with JSF, so I will keep homebrewing stuff, but I definitely keep this project in mind.

Comment: When wondering why the validator is not working attach this to the faces-config.xml in the META-INF between the <faces-config> Tag

<validator>
  <validator-id>equalsValidator</validator-id>
  <validator-class>com.yourpackage.EqualsValidator</validator-class>
 </validator>

Comment: @ImproveAnything That only required when you're still using the jurassic JSF 1.x from nearly a decade ago when configuration annotations weren't that common.